# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Totem video player crashes on launch

Tags: 22.04, video-player, gstreamer, totem

The Totem video player is crashing on launch, it was working yesterday but now it stopped working. Launching it from terminal gives me this:

> (totem:33272): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 16:29:23.486:
> gst_caps_from_string: assertion 'string' failed
>
> (totem:33272): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 16:29:23.486:
> gst_pad_template_new: assertion 'caps != NULL' failed
>
> (totem:33272): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 16:29:23.486:
> gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
>
> (totem:33272): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 16:29:23.486:
> gst_element_class_add_pad_template: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD_TEMPLATE
> (templ)' failed
>
> (totem:33272): GStreamer-Video-CRITICAL **: 16:29:23.486:
> gst_video_decoder_init: assertion 'pad_template != NULL' failed
>
> (totem:33272): GStreamer-WARNING **: 16:29:23.487: Element
> vaapidecode0 has an ALWAYS template src, but no pad of the same name
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this issue after a driver update. I was able to fix this problem on Ubuntu 22.04.2 by:

- `sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi`
- `rm -r ~/.cache/totem`
- `rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/`

Comment: Thanks ! That helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `gstreamer-vaapi` package fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I don't know but it started working again after updating Ubuntu and GPU driver.